# Requesting only features within bbox from WFS

Tags: pyqgis, wfs, bbox

I'm trying to use PyQgis to query a WFS-service and return the items found within a certain bounding box.

When entering the following uri in the browser, it returns a xml with a limited set of results

```
uri = 'https://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/overdrachtdiensten/GRB/wfs?request=getFeature&srsname=EPSG:31370&typename=GRB:ADP&BBOX=183918,186419,184189,186632,EPSG:31370'
```

Using PyQgis I wish to load this into QGIS (3.4.3):

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "WFS_Layer", "WFS")
print(layer.isValid())
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.addMapLayer(layer)
```

The layer which loads, loads all the data within my view extent, not just the data I requested in BBOX.
Afterwards I need to get some attributes of the loaded data, therefor I wish to limit the amount of data, as loading times easily get too high.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

Reading the link below, I think it's a chosen behaviour in the Qgis implementation. Is there any way to circumvent this?
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8871

I also tried the solution provided in the question below, but had no luck.
[Why doesn't QGIS show the results from a WFS BBOX from a Python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86496/why-doesnt-qgis-show-the-results-from-a-wfs-bbox-from-a-python-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this default behaviour cannot be overwritten.
So to solve my problem, I finally decided to just download the files locally through WFS and load these.

The code is given below, in capital what to change to your own values (+ change epsg value)

```
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO  # Python 3

proj_xmin= INTVALUE
proj_xmax= INTVALUE
proj_ymin= INTVALUE
proj_ymax= INTVALUE


print('Beginning file download with urllib2...')

url = 'YOURSERVERURL&BBOX='+str(int(proj_xmin))+','+str(int(proj_ymin))+','+str(int(proj_xmax))+','+str(int(proj_ymax))+',EPSG:31370&outputFormat=shape-zip'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
#filename = response.info()['Content-Disposition'].split('=')[-1]
foldername = 'FOLDERLOCATION'
data = response.read()
try:
    with BytesIO() as zipdata:
        zipdata.write(data)
        myzipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipdata)
        myzipfile.extractall(foldername)
        myzipfile.close()
except:
    print('Could not write the files')

# Add vectorlayer to Qgis 3.x
iface.addVectorLayer(foldername+"/SHAPENAME.shp", "", "ogr")
```